# How to change cellspacing at top only?

Tags: html, html-table, blogger, cellspacing

Blog: www.amedecrwanda.blogspot.com

On the homepage post I've set the table as: `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="50">`

But it affects spacing at the top too, pushing the table further down the page. Anyone got a fix for this - to keep spacing between columns the same, but remove the gap at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Remove those lines:

```
<div class="post-header">
<div class="post-header-line-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make cellspacing zero for table. Add margin for  for that particular table using CSS. In this way, you can control the way space (margin) from top.

```
<style>
table td{
margin:20px;
margin-top:0px;
}
</style>

<table cellspacing="">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="50">` with `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="">` and yes of course you should add the css styles advised by @vishal kokate